# Access rails server from host machine

Tags: virtualbox, nat, portforwarding, webrick

My rails server (WEBrick 1.3.1) is set on the virtual machine (ubuntu 12.04) and use NAT. The default IP address is 10.0.2.15 with port 3000. How can I access from my host machine (win8) ?

I have tried to use port forwarding but it doesn't work.

Settings -> Network -> Port forwarding

Protocol | Host IP | Host Port | Guest IP | Guest Port

TCP         127.0.0.1     3308      10.0.2.15      3000

Comment: why are you using NAT mode?bridged mode is easier if you want direct connection to your virtual machine.

Comment: @yogipriyo, you are not addressing the question.

Comment: @tony.0919, after setting up port forwarding did you attempt to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:3308? Using your port forwarding settings I was able to access my rails application via a browser on my windows machine.

Comment: Hi @Tass, I just want to know the reason why he's using NAT. Because most of the time that I have read before, the owner post didn't know yet the best networking mode for their case.

Comment: @yogipriyo, I do concur that it's the easiest setting if attempting to access a virtualmachine guest from its host. As someone who has asked a few questions on here I know how frustrating it can be when people suggest you do something else. Port forwarding using a NAT connection is a viable option which he/she wants to function properly. We need to be mindful of the person asking the question and focus on resolving his/her issue.

Comment: Also, based on the port forwarding information @tony.0919 provided I'd suspect the virtual machine in question is a virtualbox instance. That means that NAT is the default setting for the network adapter.

Answer (score 1):

By setting your port forwarding as you did, you are telling your host PC that when you visit `127.0.0.1` at port `3308` in your browser, you want that resolved to be your guest virtual machine's I.P. address at port `3000`.

With your virtual machine's Rails server running, open a browser on your host PC and navigate to `127.0.0.1:3308`.

If your browser doesn't render your guest server's web pages, I'd suspect you have a port conflict (that port 3308 may already be in use). In that case, search for ways to view what ports are currently in use on your PC. Find a port which is not in use and use that in your port forwarding's `host port` settings.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone faces the same problem, after port forwarding, I resolved this problem running the server binding the ip address of the virtual machine like this:

```
rails server -b 10.0.2.15
```

Comment: Had the same problem, the port forwarding is fine, it is the way it binds. I used the simpler:    `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`